# kvm guest Network interface no Authenication

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm

i have a kvm host based on ubuntu 10.04 host , and the guest is rhel 5.3 64-bit,

on the guest i tried to execute mii-tool eth0

```
SIOCGMIIREG on eth0 failed: Input/output error
SIOCGMIIREG on eth0 failed: Input/output error
eth0: no autonegotiation, 100baseTx-FD, link ok
```

and mii-tool -v eth4

```
eth0: no autonegotiation, 100baseTx-FD, link ok
  product info: vendor 00:50:43, model 2 rev 0
  basic mode:   software reset, autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
```

and mii-tool -r eth0 this is output /var/log/message

```
Feb 20 13:16:44 xil1 kernel: [ 1289.790780] e1000: eth4 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

so that it is supposed to work with 1000MB/s but it still working with 100MB/s any suggestion what may be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually **mii-tool** will show you the ethernet cable speed that is connected to your system. But the capacity of **ethernet card** might be different.

so, you can see the capacity of your ethernet card by using **lshw (listing hardware)** command in linux (ubuntu).

You are seeing in 1000 in log because of it shows you interface card capacity that it can handle.

Comment: thanks for your help ,but the lshw aso show that "capacity: 1GB/s" the actual problem is not with mii-tool or whatever the problem is that the network speed can't work perfectly with 1GB/s ! any suggestions please ?

Comment: Your capacity will show only that your card is able to handle the packets that will come with the speed of 1GB/s. But for that your lan wire should be of 1000base/tx.

Comment: it is because it is a guest kvm machine and its network speed is not perfect but the host is working perfect